# Change the icon for mat-radio-button

Tags: html, angular, angularjs-directive, angular-material

How could I change the mat-radio-button to check-mark and cross-mark looks like following? 
Thank you! 
My code is here:

```
<mat-radio-group  class="radio" (change)="onChange($event)" 
name="exemplars">
      <mat-radio-button class="radio-custom" [value]="true" [checked]="function()"> Accept </mat-radio-button>
      <mat-radio-button class="radio-custom" [value]="false" [checked]="function()"> Reject</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

icons I want to use :

[image]

Comment: Maybe did you find the solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

Don't think this is the most elegant solution but it does the job.

1. In my case I'm using Angular 10 (2+) with all the `::ng-deep` stuff so align the code for your needs.
2. I'm using an `icomoon` font with the icons my company is using so take this into consideration when applying this solution.

In my `app.component.` styling file:

```
::ng-deep {
    .mat-radio-button {

        .mat-radio-container {

            .mat-radio-outer-circle:before {
                font-family: "icomoon" !important; // here comes the icomoon font reference that defines the actual icon to be shown
                content: "\e901"; // the code of the icon from my iconfont => change this one to the X icon of yours
                position: absolute; // this and next 3 lines are for centering the icon in the circle of the radio button
                left: 50%;
                top: 50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            }

            .mat-radio-inner-circle {
                /* feel free to design the actual inner radiobutton circle as you wish*/
            }
        }

        .mat-radio-button .mat-radio-checked {

            .mat-radio-container {

                .mat-radio-outer-circle:before {
                    content: "\e900"; // the code of the icon from my iconfont => change this one to V icon of yours
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Feel free to enhance the code with all other stuff: sizes, borders, coloring, etc.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new directive that binds to mat-radio-button or any other selector you need, e.g. mat-radio-button.radio-custom
2. Inject ElementRef into the directive's constructor
3. Use the instance of ElementRef to find .mat-radio-inner-circle
4. Set the innerHTML of the found html element to the svg of your desired icon.

Example:

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'mat-radio-button',
})
export class CustomRadioButton implements OnInit {
  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.appendIcon();
  }

  appendIcon() {
    const innerCircle = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.mat-radio-inner-circle');

    innerCircle.innerHTML = YOUR_SVG_CODE;
  }
}
```